# nesting html with php foreach statement

Tags: php, html, loops, foreach

I am trying to get back into the foreach statement, as seen in the example code below. 
is there a way to do that?

```
<?php 
    foreach($boxes as $box) 
    {
       foreach($box as $thing) 
       {
?>
        <img src="<?php echo $thing ?>"/>
<?php
       }  
    }
?>

<!-- more html code here outside of foreach statement that don't want to be loop -->

// want to go back in to the foreach statement     

<?php echo $thing; ?>
```

so the output will be

```
<img src="1">
<img src="2">
<img src="3">

<div>this only appear once</div>

<img src="1"><p>1</p>
<img src="2"><p>2</p>
<img src="3"><p>3</p>
```

Comment: I want to print out the same thing in the same order again. not really sure what do you mean by interpolate.

Comment: Wouldn't you just run the loops again? (Have another `foreach` loop in the next section you required it?)

Comment: save the foreach result to a variable and print the variable afterwards at the places you want it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [I want to print out the same thing in the same order again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27308557/nesting-html-with-php-foreach-statement/27308600#comment43079074_27308557)

By that logic, you could define a function:

```
function outputBoxes($boxes) {
    foreach($boxes as $box) {
        foreach($box as $thing) { // you can make the next two lines valid with ?>
            <!-- html code here -->
            <img src="<?php echo $thing ?>"/>
        <?php } // and now we're back in PHP
    }
}
```

Then use `outputBoxes($boxes)` anytime you want that to make that `foreach` loop happen again.

@Prix also brings a valid argument since we like to avoid frivolous looping as programmers:

```
function outputBoxes($boxes) {
    $out = '';
    foreach ($boxes as $box) {
        foreach ($box as $thing) {
            $out .= '<!-- html code here -->' .
                    '<img src=' . $thing . ' />';
        }
    }
    return $out;
}
```

Then you can `echo outputBoxes($boxes);` or `$boxHtml = outputBoxes($boxes);` and just `echo $boxHtml;` as much as we want. Dealer's choice!

Comment: I like the function ideas thank you.  i guess i just didn't really think it through.

Comment: @wlin Cheers! Make sure you accept the answer that you feel has best solved your question.

Answer (score 0):

if you mean the foreach will print the html code n times, just put the curly bracket under the html code. But you have 2 foreach there so I don't know which one. I'll just put both close bracket down.

```
    <?php 
        foreach($boxes as $box) {
                  foreach($box as $thing) {
                        <!-- html code here -->
                        <img src='<?php echo $thing ?>'/>
    ?>

    <!-- more html code here outside of foreach statement that don't want to be loop -->

    // want to go back in to the foreach statement     

    <?php 
echo $thing;
                  }  
        }

?>
```

As far as I know, every html code outside

```
<?php ?>
```

tag will be treated as echo "html code" when the PHP intepreter reads PHP file.